# How to use Acumatica Web Service in .net 3.5 CE - No cookie container

Tags: c#, cookies, acumatica

I am trying to develop a windows mobile application for barcode devices and I have problems integrating to Acumatica Web Service. The problem that I'm having is that the framework that windows mobiles uses (.net 3.5 CE) doesn't have a cookiecontainer.

Do you have any idea on how I will store my cookies?

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach could be to create a proxy which avoids the need of cookies to communicate with the Acumatica Web Services. Some of the WMS products that work with Acumatica use this technique (through a pure TCP/IP proxy), since it's also very lightweight and gives you more control on the payload that you transmit.

Otherwise, you may take a look at this article on MSDN which suggest working directly with the HTTP headers and manage the cookies yourself: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/34d88228-0b68-4fda-a8cd-58efe6b47958/no-cookies-sessionstate-in-compact-framework?forum=vssmartdevicesvbcs